# I want to make a REPL-style program with pipes and signals, but my program locks

Tags: c, posix, signals, fifo

The program should fork, then the parent should read user input, send it to the child; the child should deal with it, then send a result to the parent, who prints it (it is required to work this way).

I've done a part of it, but the program locks after reading from the fifo the first time.

I suspect the problem is somewhere between lines 122–199. Making the pipe nonblocking makes the program jump through the scanf at 185 and loop indefinitely. Closing and reopening the pipe before writing and after reading leads to the same effect.

Here is the source: [link](http://pylonshq.com/pasties/990228babd3c0e83bc61aaa4c4d2fb1f).

---

Later edit (clarification):

The parent blocks before the printf at 184, when it reads the second command (the first time it seems to work just fine).

I haven't implemented the "child sends stuff back to the parent" part. At the moment I just want to make the child output the data it recieves through the pipe from the parent and then give control back to the parent to read another command.

The child lives in a paused state (pause()) while the parent reads input and sends it through the pipe, then it wakes up the child and goes in a paused state itself. The child reads data from the pipe and outputs it, then wakes up the parent and goes to sleep.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you use some multiplexing system call like `select` or `poll` which are able to test of a set of file descriptors has some of them ready (for input, or for output)?

Learn more about [poll](http://linux.die.net/man/2/poll) or about [select](http://linux.die.net/man/2/select_tut) and friends.

Comment: It seems to be what I need. I'll look into it. Thanks!

Comment: Actually, you might prefer to use some existing infrastructure for that (because the devil is in the details). Many libraries provide event processing infrastructure (Glib from GTK3, Libevent, libev, QTCore from QT4, etc...)

Answer (score 0):

You should clarify your question which with part (parent or child) it is that locks.

Make sure all output is line feed terminated. It seems (from a quick reading) that you use `puts()`, which should take care of that.

Try calling `fflush()` on the output after the client is done, to make sure the output gets written to the pipe, if the child lives on while the parent reads its output. I didn't read your code closely enough to track down the lifetime handling.

Comment: I've updated the question with more info.  Calling `fflush()` after the child is done makes the program jump through the `scanf()` at 185 and loop. I tried replacing the `printf("$ ");` (184) with `puts("say something:");`... `printf` doesn't seem to be the problem.